# Creation of Excel Sheet and Fetching Rows from that

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to run several steps involving excel sheet through Windows Scheduler. Below are those :

1. Clear the data residing in the excel sheet ( sheet is located at some point)
2. Run a command through cmd which dumps fresh data into that excel sheet.
3. Checking of certain fields in the rows of that excel sheet.
4. Sending email based upon the results of checks applied in step 3.

Can anyone suggest what is the best way of doing above?
Should I write all above steps in a .bat file and then run that through Windows Scheduler? If yes, Can anyone guide me how to start with it? Or is there any other better way of doing this task?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's probably better done with VBA. However, welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Which data source have you got? For starters, I'd create a csv file, then would use `findstr` for checks. For conversion see  http://stackoverflow.com/q/31606394/5494004 In order to send search for a command line mail client, and you've got a batch to make a scheduled task with